# Run one os over four servers

Tags: grid, cloud, cluster-computing

I have four servers that i want to make to one server and run windows or linux on that?
e.g. all servers got 8 cores so in the os it will be 32 cores. Is that possible? I thinking of Amazon aren't they doing this?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not possible. What amazon is providing you is basically a distributed system, however you need to deal with the fact that it is a distributed system. In your example it is a system of four nodes with each 8 cores and not a system with 32 cores. Using cluster software the system can give the abstraction of a single-system image. However because it is cluster, the user will pay a certain performance penalty. In addition you will be limited by the scalability of a individual node if the workload cannot be very well parallelized.